# Appended strings producing a string that is multiple lines

Tags: c++, string, text-files

I am trying to write a program that figures out the path to a person's desktop (on macOS) and creates a text file. For testing, I made it output the path as well. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char text[255]; //finds username first
       FILE *name;
       name = popen("whoami", "r");
       fgets(text, sizeof(text), name);
      

std::string path1 = "/Users/";  //strings are "added" to create 1 (test1) 
std::string pathvar = text; 
std::string pathend = "/Desktop/test.txt\n"; 
std::string fullpath= path1 + pathvar + pathend; 
std::cout << fullpath << "\n"; 

std::string test2; //strings are appended to create 1 (test2)
test2.append("/Users/");
test2.append(text); 
test2.append("/Desktop/test.txt"); 
std::cout << test2 << "\n"; 
std::ofstream outfile (fullpath);

outfile << "test!" << "\n";

outfile.close();

}
```

However, the paths it outputs are divided between two lines, like this:

```
/Users/username
/Desktop/test.txt
```

and the program does not output the text file on my desktop.
I've tried concatenating and appending the strings, but both ways turn out broken. How do I fix it so that the assembled string is one line and the program produces a text file? Thank you!

Comment: `fgets` is documented to include the newline character in the string it reads. So `pathvar` has a trailing newline character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the pathvar string, I deleted "\n" from it using this:

```
pathvar.erase(std::remove(pathvar.begin(), pathvar.end(), '\n'),
        pathvar.end());
```

Which fixed the outputted path and allowed for the creation of the text file on my desktop.

The original issue was due to `fget` including `\n` when reading the "whoami" file, causing a new line to begin, separating the full path into two lines and preventing the text file from being generated.

(Thanks to @Igor Tandetnik for helping me)

Comment: You should also add the explanation of why you got the bug in the first place.